# url functions in as2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

This is from ActionScript 2.0 not a big one, but enough to keep me wondering what is wrong.
 This code works perfectly when I hit button in original swf file but when I publish it as html or embed it in html document there is no response. What to do?

```
on (release) { URL("aboutus.html"); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
on(release) { getURL("aboutus.html"); }
```

Comment: Is the url valid? Do you have [debug version of flash player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) installed? That will give you more insight to whats going on